# Add url parameters to a url in django view

Tags: django, filter

I have a django view that lists several urls on external sites.

When I render them I would like to add a few url parameters to each.

These urls are to an external system and thus not listed in my urls.py. Furthermore, some of the links have a hash '#' so it is not as easy as appending a few parameters to the end of the string.

Based on these requirements it seems the url template tag will not be a good fit. I was wondering if there is a custom filter out that to do this.

Comment: Why would you need the url tag? It would help if you could create an [mcve]

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. The `url` template tag is for generating URLs that are within your own site/project. If you want to add links to external sites then why not just put them in the HTML, URL parameters and all?

Comment: This seems odd to me why would you need a thirdparty application to solve this problem. Seems like typing `?foo=bar&pop=lol` is a lot less key strokes then the `pip install` + `add_query="foo=bar"` etc.

Comment: @marcusshep that's not entirely true. what about url fragments(#)? the params need to come before it. what if there are already url params? you don't need to add the '?'. I agree it's not a lot of code but there are definitely edge cases here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Django's `url` tag here. The `url` tag is to *resolve* to URLs that belong to *your* application.

However, there is the nice [django-spurl](https://github.com/j4mie/django-spurl) library. It allows you to handle query parameters via template tags.

An example from the [documentation](https://github.com/j4mie/django-spurl#add_query) to add query parameters:

```
{% spurl base="http://example.com/?foo=bar" add_query="bar=baz" %}

<!--
will result in: http://example.com?foo=bar&bar=baz 
-->
```